# $q.all returns undefined for all values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to wait on 3 promises but `$q.all` appears to resolve them at once and returns `undefined`for each single value, I can't figure out why:

```
this.doWork = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var a = get('a'),
    b = get('b'),
    c = get('c');
  $q.all([a.promise, b.promise, c.promise])
    .then(function(values) {
      deferred.resolve(new Test(values[0], values[1], values[2]));
    }, function(reason) {
      deferred.reject(reason);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
};

function get(param) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $timeout(function() {
    if (true) {
      deferred.resolve({
        value: param
      });
    } else {
      deferred.reject({
        message: "Really bad"
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

(in the actual code `get()` uses `$http` instead of `$timeout`, of course). Here's a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3aE63U0Q2wzkWdSiEDld) with the code, can anybody please shed some light on what the issue is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be doing `.promise` on `promise` object returned by `get` method, because you had already returned `promise` form `get` method.

```
$q.all([a, b, c])
```

> When you're doing `a.promise`, `b.promise` & `c.promise` they all becomes
>   `undefined` & then `$q.all` array become `$q.all([undefined, undefined, undefined])` passing them to `$q.all` will give `undefined` result.

Comment: That was indeed the problem (*pulls hair out*) - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Aredhel Glad to know that.. Thanks :)