# $q promise with foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I am writing an angular service to work with SharePoint data and I have run into a problem. I have a function in my service that updates and single item and returns an $http promise which works fine. The problem is I am trying to write a function now that utilizes the first function to loop and update multiple items. I want it to return a single promise once all items have been updated and it should reject if any of the items being updated failed. Here is the function:

```
this.UpdateListItems = function (webUrl, listName, itemsJson) {
    if (numItems == -1) {
        numItems = itemsJson.length;
        c = 0;
        f = 0;
    }
    var promises = [];

    itemsJson.forEach(function (itemProps) {
        var itemPromise = this.UpdateListItem(webUrl, listName, itemProps.Id, itemProps)
            .then(function (response) {
                c++;
                if (c == numItems && f == 0) {
                    numItems = -1;
                    return itemsJson[listName];
                }
            }, function (error) {
                c++; f++;
                alert("ERROR!");//This gets called first alert below
                if (c == numItems) {
                    numItems = -1;
                    return $q.reject(error);
                }
            });
        promises.push(itemPromise.$promise)
    }, this);
    return $q.all(promises)
        .then(function (data) {
            alert("IN SUCCESS"); //This always gets called immediately after first item success instead of waiting for all items to finish
        }, function (error) {
            alert("IN ERROR"); //This never gets called
        });
};
```

The $q.all is returning immediately after the first item returns successfully instead of waiting for the rest of the async item calls. Any help is much appreciated, I am new to all this. Thanks!

EDIT: Adding UpdateListItem code as requested:

```
this.UpdateListItem = function (webUrl, listName, itemId, itemProperties) {
    if (typeof lists[listName] === 'undefined') {
        lists[listName] = [];
    }
    var post = angular.copy(itemProperties);
    DataUtilitySvc.ConvertDatesJson(post);
    return this.GetListItemById(webUrl, listName, itemId)
        .then(function (item) {
            return $http({
                url: item.__metadata.uri,
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                processData: false,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(post),
                dataType: "json",
            }).then(function (response) {
                var temp = [];
                temp.push(itemProperties);
                DataUtilitySvc.MergeByProperty(lists[listName], temp, 'Id');
                return response;
            }, function (error) {
                return $q.reject(error);
            });
        }, function (error) {
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `this.UpdateListItem` function already returned promise by having `$promise` object. That's why you were able to have `.then`(chain promise) function over it.

So basically you just need to push returned `itemPromise` object instead of having `itemPromise.$promise` inside `promises` array. Basically when you are doing `$promise`, it creates an array of `[undefined, undefined, ...]` and will resolve as soon as for loop completed.

Change to

```
promises.push(itemPromise)
```

from

```
promises.push(itemPromise.$promise)
```

Somewhat this question can relate to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548484/2435473)

Comment: Alright so I did this and it reversed the alerts. Now the ERROR! alert triggers first and then the IN SUCCESS alert triggers. Closer, it is waiting for them all now but it is always going into the IN SUCCESS part even if one of the items fails.

Comment: @NathanKamenar could you add `this.UpdateListItem` code? any console errors?

Comment: I added it and yes there is one error but it is expected. I am updating 3 items for testing but one of the items I request to update doesn't exist which triggers a 404 error

Comment: I had another typo I hadn't seen before, this is working as intended, thanks.

Comment: @NathanKamenar Glad to know that helped.. Thanks :-)